# How to find a paid version of an app?

Tags: google-play-store, search, paid-apps

I want to buy Clash of Clans pro version and install it on my device. I found that this game has pro/premium version available. I went to Play Store to install it. I searched this game's pro version with queries  "clash of clans pro" and "clash of clans premium", but I only found the free version.

So, how to find out the paid version of an app whose free version is available? Example: ES File Explorer has both free and paid versions available. Any easy way to find paid version?

Comment: Regarding CoC, where did you find that there's a pro/premium version? Possibly it's a scam/hack, and is off-topic on here.

Comment: @AndrewT. : Uh, did I just hastily answered an off-topic question? I didn't think of it as off-topic.

Comment: @Firelord I'm clarifying about finding off-site resource if it's really about the pro/premium version, which seems like a hacked version of the game.

Comment: I've added the tag [tag:google-play-store]. This may appear to be changing the original intent. Feel free to remove it if it does change the intent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can't find an app that doesn't exist, and I don't think that apps that *do* have paid versions are typically hard to find -- and there's no single answer for that anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every developer creates and puts a premium version of an app separately into a market. A developer can have a single app but have mechanism to make the user unlock certain parts of the app by paying for it. This is called in-app billing.

Google in the document [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) noted:

> In-app Billing is a Google Play service that **lets you sell digital content from inside your applications**. You can use the service to **sell a wide range of content, including downloadable content such as media files or photos, virtual content such as game levels or potions, premium services and features, and more**. You can use In-app Billing to sell products as
>
> - Standard in-app products (one-time billing), or
> - Subscriptions (recurring, automated billing)

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

The app [Clash Of Clans](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans) supports in-app billing.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

---

If a developer (any individual or a company) did put a premium version of an app, then the easiest way to find it is to open the developer's page and go through all of their apps currently published in that market. It makes sense that both the apps would have the same developer behind it or at least the same public name (pen name) of them.

In your particular case, the app Clash Of Clans is *published* by Supercell and [their page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6715068722362591614) doesn't show any premium version of that app.

It is easy to search the developer's page by using Play Store from a web browser. Simply click the developer's name and there you go. <strike>Same cannot be said for Play Store app.</strike>

#### Edit:

In Play Store app, use this query:

```
pub:PUBLISHER_NAME
```

`PUBLISHER_NAME` is **case sensitive** here and should be replaced by name of the publisher of app, so ELECTRONIC ARTS would work but not Electronic Arts or any combination of uppercase and lowercase letters in that name.

Example:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Source for edit: [Linking to a Product List](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher)

Comment: sorry,but i dont find coc pro on supercell devloper page.any other way?

Comment: It seems that you didn't understand my answer. Let me give you a brief: *Clash Of Clans doesn't have a premium version. It supports [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html).*

Comment: but when i visit clash of clans page i seeing this massage "offerse in app purchase".

Comment: Is there something you don't understand in my answer? I don't think my answer is illegible. The point is: *you cannot purchase the game if it supports in-app billing but only the items it offers*. To purchase them, see https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1061913

Comment: @andieo you must understand different paid apps have different business models. Some apps give you *in-game* options to pay for things like upgrades.

Comment: So,i think clash of clans pro version not available on the market.but i purchase gems in app.it is called "in app billing".i am right?

Comment: @andieo : Yes, you're correct.